# PHP - AJAX and MySQL - Query error

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database

In the last couple days I set up my own local web server and began to develop a prototype web application. This web application is simple for now. I have a dropdown list with names of MySQL tables and a div that will update with all of the rows of the selected table. Yes, the div properly updated when I tried a simple query to select * from table_name.

However, I'm bringing in AJAX now to add functionality to the dropdown list and the div will not update. I used the code from W3 but their query is different than mine, otherwise it does work with a query that doesn't use a variable as a table name. I've pinpointed the exact problem through trial and error and I have no idea how to fix it. *(I've looked for the answer online already)* The AJAX script uses a function that is called when an item on the dropdown list is selected. Once the item is selected the AJAX does its requests and then sends the variable to the php file. The php file has successfully grabbed the information but only when I do queries such as:

```
    $sql = "select * from table_name where Price = '" . $q . "'";
```

**The exact issue:** I'm trying to use the variable as the table name and I've formatted the string every possible way I could think of but the string is just wrong. I keep getting the error **"mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result"** but I've been down this path before so I know this is because of the SQL query string. *(I've also tried different mysqli_fetch functions)*

Alright here is how my code looks just in case you need some insight, but I'm confident this is about the query.

**AJAX SCRIPT**

```
    function showUser(str) {
        if (str === "") {
            document.getElementById("playerList").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                    document.getElementById("playerList").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q=" + str, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
```

**PHP CODE**

```
    <?php

    $q = intval($_GET['q']);

    require 'conn.php';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $q";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //echo with html formatting
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

I've tried formatting the query several different ways

```
    $query = "select * from `$q`";

    $query = "select * from `" . $q . "`";

    $query = "select * from "$q"";

    $query = "select * from " . $q . "";

    $query = "select * from '" . $q . "'";

    //I've even tried this, and it works but it's not dynamic because it's not using the variable!
    $table = "table_name";
    $query = "select * from $table_name";
```

Comment: `$q` is your table name? That's very dangerous, just ask Bobby Tables. Since you're `intval` it, `$q` semantically appears to be an ID, so I suspect you want `SELECT * FROM user WHERE id="$q"` (but use prepared statements instead of direct inline).

Comment: @bijan kelly your query in wrong. where is table name.

Comment: I need to select all from user, so do I need to change from intval?

Comment: remove the intval function from the first line of getuser.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace  `intval($_GET['q']);` To `$_GET['q'];`

Comment: Thank you, I'm still learning php and I didn't catch the conversion to an integer